# On Fibonacci sequence

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ and $F_m$ be two terms of Fibonacci sequence such that $m<n$.

Is there an upper bound $c<1$, such that
$\dfrac{F_m}{F_n}<c$ ?

Comment: For all $m$ and $n$ such that $m < n$? Two successive terms (first and second or second and third, depending on the definition of the sequence) of the Fibonacci sequence are $1$ and $1$, so then we'd have $1/1 = 1$.

Comment: You can't have anything more than $1$ except if you add an extra condition

Comment: For large $m<n$ you have $$\frac{F_m}{F_n} <c$$ for every constant $c \ge \frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$

Comment: @Crostul That along with the fact that $F_n$ is increasing tells us that there definitely exists at least one $c < 1$ which works for all $m < n$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score -1):

> Let $F_n$ and $F_m$ be two terms of Fibonacci sequence such that  $m<n$

> Is there an upper bound $c<1$, such that
> $\dfrac{F_m}{F_n}<c$ ?

> For large $m<n$ you have $c \geq \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$  [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724226/on-fibonacci-sequence/4724236#comment10010314_4724226)

The statement is false as we can demonstrate by the data that: $\dfrac{F_m}{F_n}> c$ where $c=1$ and $m < n$. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3YtJ.png)

Furthermore, we know that $c \geq \phi = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$  [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724226/on-fibonacci-sequence/4724236#comment10010314_4724226)

To prove this:

$$\lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty, \infty)} (\frac{F_m}{F_n}) \stackrel{m < n}{\implies} \lim_{(n,m) \to (\infty, \infty)} (\frac{F_m}{F_n})<1$$

Furthermore, here we have an Excel computation for some finite examples:

[image]

Comment: The question clearly says that $m < n$.

Comment: @Crostul, yes but by demonstrating the contrary, I can demonstrate the question asked, or am I wrong? (This seems to be called proof by contraposition)

Comment: @Crostul I've now tried to demonstrate the actual question asked.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Answer (score -1):

(Throughout this answer it is assumed that we don't consider the case $F_m=F_n=1$, i.e. we only look at the strictly increasing part of the Fibonacci numbers.)

Using the observation from Crostul here is a proof that there exists some $c<1$ s.t. $\frac{F_m}{F_n}<c$ for all $m<n$.

We use the fact that the limit of $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ as $n$ tends to infinity is $\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}>1$.

Using the definition of the limit, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N_{\epsilon}$ s.t. $|\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\phi|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N_{\epsilon}$.

Choosing any $0<\epsilon<\phi-1$ we can see that, letting $\delta=\phi-1-\epsilon$, for all $n>N_{\epsilon}$, $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}>1+\delta$ and so $\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}<\frac{1}{1+\delta}<1$

Now as $F_n$ is strictly increasing $\frac{F_m}{F_n}$ is maximised with $n=m+1$ and so if $m>N_{\epsilon}$, $\frac{F_m}{F_n}<\frac{1}{1+\delta}$.

There are finitely many $m$ with $m \leq N_{\epsilon}$ and so $M=\max(\{\frac{F_m}{F_{m+1}}, m \leq N_{\epsilon}\})$ exists.

As $F_n$ is increasing $M<1$. And so $c=\max(M,\frac{1}{1+\delta})$<1 and for all $m<n$, $\frac{F_m}{F_n}<c$

$\blacksquare$

Finding the minimal such $c$ should essentially just be an exercise in computation.

Additionally essentially the same argument shows that for any sequence $a_n$ the existance of a $c$ as described is equivalent to the sequence being strictly increasing and having $\liminf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ (or combined $\inf(\{ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}, n \in \Bbb{N}$})>1 ).

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.